# How can I determine whether a device is using 12 or 24-hour time format?

Tags: android, android-date

I want to know the current device time format, meaning 24 hour/ 12 hour format.

Please let me know how can I determine that.

Are there any API there to determine this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

<strike>`String value = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24);`</strike>

Updated Answer, you should use this instead of the above, as above could give back a null value:

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
```

Comment: *Caution:* Using this can result in a null value being returned to your application. As specified in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7922264/181211 , a better solution is `DateFormat.is24HourFormat()` . MrJre, I recommend updating your answer.

Comment: This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Note that there are several classes called `DateFormat`, the one that you want is `android.text.format.DateFormat`.

Answer (score 9):

This may help you....

The link of the answer source: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context)

Answer (score 0):

I'm reporting something that seems an issue with Android 13: if the flag "use locale default" is on the device settings shows eg:

5:44 and the DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context) returns true

if I disable the option and leave the "Use 24 hour format" off it works properly.

Anyone has another solution to check if the clock on the status bar is 12 or 24h format?

[image: Time is displayed in am/pm format]
[image: Use locale default is on]