# timepicker: when to choose 24 or am/pm modes

Tags: android

I have a few timepickers in my app.

In my country (Spain) we are used to displaying time in 24 hours mode... but in other countries are used to am/pm.

I know how to set a Timepicker to 24 or am/pm mode...
But what is the best approach to show am/pm or 24 depending of the device locale or country? How can I know to select one or another mode?

Thank you very much

(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Ditto what wonder.mice says. There are some tedious but necessary checks being done for you in android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, of which the first is to just use the device settings and thus let the user make this decision, but be aware that **this can return a null value in some cases** and is therefore not as reliable;

```
String clockType = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
```

**A better solution** is given by wonder.mice, which is using:

```
boolean is24HourFormat = DateFormat.is24HourFormat();
```

see also the reference page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context)

Answer (score 13):

Use DateFormat from android.text.format.DateFormat:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

As can be seen from sources (frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/format/DateFormat.java) function DateFormat.is24HourFormat() does much more than just asking for TIME_12_24 from Settings.System.

As I understand DateFormat.is24HourFormat() is a more reliable way to get users time format. For example, because Settings.System.getString() can return null for TIME_12_24 (as seen from DateFormat.java).