# How can I format a time on mobile website using device's 12/24 hour time setting?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I'm building a mobile (iOS/Android) website where I'd like to format times based on the device's 12/24 hour setting (On iOS in Settings > General > Date & Time). Is there any way to get the value of that setting in JavaScript?

The closest answer I found is that I can use [Moment.js's `LT` format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) which formats times as 12 or 24 hours based on the locale. But regardless of the locale set, they could override the 12/24 hour setting (at least on iOS), so I'd prefer to respect that setting.

Since this mobile website will be embedded in a webview in a native app one approach I'm considering is reading the value of that setting in native [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236693/62)/[Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650630/62) code and passing it into the website via a query string parameter, but was hoping to not have to update native code to solve this.